# Adding ambient light to images rendered with ColorRenderCamera()

Tags: drake

I am trying to build a manipulation station in Drake to prototype an image-based planning algorithm.

I am mostly using the code from the [Rendering MultibodyPlant Tutorial](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/rendering_multibody_plant.ipynb) to render images. The renderer seems to be using a fixed light-source attached to the camera and something similar to phong shading with a small ambient term, so all surfaces parallel to the camera take on a black color (i.e., because the dot product between the surface normal and the incoming light goes to zero in diffuse illumination). [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCVpe.png) shows the result. The meshcat visualizer has ambient illumination so it doesn't have this issue, as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khL64.jpg) shows. (The obj file has baked-in in illumination, that is why there are shadows and other effects in both images)

Is there a way for me to either add ambient light or turn off diffuse shading completely when using ColorRenderCamera() from the python API? I tried altering the  tags in the sdf file to add ambient light or turn-off shading, but this didn't have any effect.

Thanks a lot for the help!

(Also, thanks a lot for the tutorials and generally making everything open-source, it is very helpful)

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial, I assume you're using `MakeRenderEngineVtk`. There is another render engine `MakeRenderEngineGl` that has different behavior. It's generally lower quality but possibly you get lucky and it happens to work better in this case. (Note that it doesn't run on macOS yet, just Ubuntu.)

> I tried altering the tags in the sdf file to add ambient light or turn-off shading, but this didn't have any effect.

Yes, unfortunately at the moment Drake tends to ignore texture and lighting settings in most kinds of input data. See [drake#12593](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12593) for discussions configurable lighting, or [drake#11949](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/11949) and [drake#18844](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18844) for discussions of material properties. We've actively working on making this better over the next few months.

Other Drake users who understand this technology better than myself might have more tips, but possibly changing some details of the illumination in the `*.mtl` file would help. It's not entirely clear to me what parts of the obj/mtl VTK is using vs ignoring at the moment. There's a good chance that no edits there would make any difference.

Possibly the [SetDefaultLightPosition](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.render.html#pydrake.geometry.render.RenderEngine.SetDefaultLightPosition) function would help a little, though its documentation suggests not to use it and in any case moving the shadows around is not probably terribly useful for your application.